# How to get raspberry flavor into a smoothie without seeds?

Tags: seeds, raspberries, smoothie

I often enjoy (when it's not dead of winter) a fruit smoothie for breakfast; generally I use orange juice or some other juice flavor (V8 has a few with fruit flavors masking veggie tastes that I sometimes use), yogurt, and fruit I've frozen myself (removes the need for ice, leading to a thicker smoothie). Typically I use strawberries and bananas; however, when I purchase smoothies, my favorite flavors involve raspberry. I've tried purchasing frozen berries and tossing some in, but the seeds irritate me to no end.

How can I get the taste of raspberries, preferably from raspberries themselves rather than extract (seems healthier), but not the seeds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd stew the raspberries down with a little water (and sugar if the raspberries aren't sweet) until they're very soft, then pass the whole thing through a sieve to remove the seeds. You can then either store the result in the fridge, or pour it into an ice cube tray for easy portioning and a nice cold smoothie.

Comment: oooh, raspberry ice cubes would portion well - I usually put a single portion of fruit into a baggie so I can just dump it in while half asleep, so I could measure out cube sizes with whatever other fruit I'm mixing it into. Great idea!

Comment: This is how I go about raspberry lemonade, more or less, except I mash the berries with a spoon and strain it through cheese cloth. Worth noting that this will stain anything you get near it - the cloth, the spoon, the container, the counter, your shirt, ...

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple common ways to deal with seeds in berries:

- Use a [food mill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_mill), which uses a rotating blade to crush the berries and force them through small holes. They're designed for this sort of thing - removing seeds or large pieces of pulp.
- Do what the food mill does, but by hand: push them through a reasonably fine strainer/sieve. Unless they're really soft, you generally want to puree them first. You can also incorporate other ingredients first, to give more liquid to work with, so you don't have to do as much pushing.

Comment: How does this interact with the freezing process? Do I freeze the puree? Or mill frozen fruit?

Comment: +1 This is what I do. I usually add a little of the seeds back in for cosmetic reasons. You can freeze the puree. You cannot mill frozen fruit.

Comment: If your fruit is already frozen, you can simply thaw it and then use this method.  You'll have to add ice to your smoothie if you want it cold, though, and/or re-freeze the puree.

Answer (score 2):

Some brands of raspberry yoghurt don't have seeds, and you say you're adding yoghurt anyway, so you could try that.

Comment: While that will technically work, a smoothie is about fruit, and a "raspberry" yoghurt isn't fruit.

Answer (score 0):

We have invented a new product called the Smoothie Press™. It's a travel mug for smoothies that strains out berry seeds. Really cool!! Check it out here:

www.smoothiepress.com

Happy Holidays!

~Jodi

Comment: This does not appear to be spam: it is a product which solves the problem given in the question, and the affiliation is disclosed.